# How to allow writing to files via Apache and WebDAV

Tags: apache, permissions, file-permissions, webdav

I am having trouble understanding how I can get to edit files on a WebDAV setup. I have set up the Auth correctly, as verified by loads of online tutorials, yet there are some files like `.htaccess` which I can't edit.

The contents of the VirtualHost setup are

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin xxx
        ServerName xxx

        DocumentRoot /data/www/vhosts/xxx
        <Directory /data/www/vhosts/xxx>
                Options Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Location />
                DAV On
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "WebDAV Access"
                AuthUserFile /data/www/.htpasswd-webdav
                Require valid-user
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I've generated the correct username in the file too, and I can log in successfully and see all the files. Like I say, the problem is that certain files are unreadable and unwritable, the main culprits being `.htaccess` and `.gitignore`.

I have set the permissions on all files to `664` and all folders to `775` and a `user:group` of `xxx:www-data`. The reason being that this allows PHP to read/write the files ok, and our remote login user `xxx` to do the same without permissions issues.

Is there something specific I need to do to allow reading writing to these hidden dot files? I'm completely stumped, as most tutorials I've read are telling me that if I don't set the rights on dot files to `root:root` then they will be writable. I am using a Mac to connect to the WebDAV service, which runs on Ubuntu, if this makes any difference

Just for clarity, all of the `xxx` in this question is to hide info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So it seems that I can allow access to specific files using the below

```
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>
```

I forgot that `.htaccess` files are blocked over HTTP by default.

**EDIT:**

The final working setup, to make all files writeable in the webdav environment, with Digest secure authentication is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin xxx
        ServerName www.domain.name

        DocumentRoot xxx
        <Directory xxx>
                Options Indexes MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|php)$">
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        ForceType text/plain
    </FilesMatch>

        <Location />
                DAV On

                AuthType Digest
                AuthName "Webdav Access"
        AuthDigestDomain / http://www.domain.name/

        AuthDigestProvider file
                AuthUserFile /data/www/digest.users
                Require valid-user

        php_value engine off
        </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

I hope this helps someone else. It took days to find all this info out on the web.

Answer (score 1):

Also check the permissions of /data/www/ itself. It should be writable for the apache user.